# Throwing a popup when search yields no results

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

Here's the deal. Have a functioning web app using ASP.NET WebForms with a C# backend. The thing works fine, but I'm always looking to improve, as a beginner at this stuff. Right now, to deal with a user's search coming back with no results, I utilize the following, and was wondering if there was any cleaner way to do it, for future reference:

```
DataClass data = new DataClass();
var searchresults = data.GetData(searchBox.Text);
int datanumber = searchresults.Count();
if (datanumber == 0)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "javascript:alert('There were no records found to match your search');", true);
}
else
{
    DropDownList1.Visible = true;
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = searchresults;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd just rather the page say that there were no results (maybe in a red font so it stands out), rather than a popup.

Comment: Actually I don't prefer using alerts when I'm talking to a user unless he tries to leave my page and I must confirm that his data will be lost.
Most of the time I just either show a div with a nice message or an animated div that says no results were found.

Comment: @JustinSteranko - you can pretty up the popup by using a jquery popup, for example.  Personally, I find popups annoying and agree with Mike Chrstensen

Comment: Your points are all well received. I will look into putting that on the page.

Comment: What I was most interested in with this question, however, is whether I have to declare the "datanumber" variable and use the Count method or if that step was uneccesary and I could just use the IEnumerable searchresults itself.

Comment: @JustinSteranko - Yes, you could do: `if (searchresults.Count() == 0)`

Comment: Thanks Mike. I was overthinking it, as I am wont to do at this stage of my programming life.

Comment: You could create a Custom Control that accepts a Dataset (or whatever GetData is returning) and displays an inline message if the DataSet is empty. Then from your page code you could literally just do CustomDDLControl.DataSource = data.GetData(searchBox.Text);. Yes, I know you are just moving the same code from the page to the control, but if you are using the control elsewhere it will keep your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the not using popups, so you could always do something as simple as having a Label object on your page:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblResultMsg" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False" />
```

And then set the text dynamically (or add it as a property to the code) and set the label to be visible on postback if no results are found:

```
if (datanumber == 0)
{
    lblResultMsg.Text = "There were no records found to match your search.";
    lblResultMsg.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    lblResultMsg.Text = "";
    lblResultMsg.Visible = false;

    // do your data binding
}
```

But there are quite a vast number of ways you could achieve something like this.  Regarding your question about using the .Count from the Enumerable collection - there's nothing stopping you doing this as it's perfectly valid.  The question is which method do you find more readable?

Answer (score 0):

if you include the jquery ui dialog (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), you can simply call this to create a nice dialog box:

```
$('<div>message</div>').dialog({autoOpen:true,title:'Error'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to create a helper function for inserting the relevant javascript into the page, and only pass parameters to the function so that I don't need to worry about the messy details every time.

Something like :

```
public static void GrowlMessage(System.Web.UI.Control pageControl, string header = "", string message = "", bool sticky = false, string position = "top-right", string theme = "", bool closer = true, int life = 8)
{
    string _js = "$.jGrowl('" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(message) + "', { header:'" + header + "', sticky:" + sticky.ToString().ToLower() + ", position: '" + position + "', theme: '" + theme + "', closer: " + closer.ToString().ToLower() + ", life:" + life * 1000 + "});";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pageControl, pageControl.GetType(),"Growl",_js, true);            
}
```

The sample I have used also requires [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery) and the jGrowl library available [here](https://bitbucket.org/stanlemon/jgrowl). And IMHO the messages are pretty. They are unobtrusive, the user does not need to click a button to make them go away, and they fade away after your specified amount of time.

But I agree with Mike, that if you don't have any records, you should just use the built in properties of a GridView (EmptyDataRowStyle and EmptyDataRowText) to display a 'no data matching your query' style message. Assuming that you're using a GridView at all, that is..

Comment: It eventually does get passed into a gridview, but first into a dropdownlist as a secondary filter. This is to keep it in line with some of our other web applications that end users are accustomed to

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to user feedback, Impromptu is my friend.  There is a nice ASP.NET implementation of Impromptu on Aaron Goldenthal's website: http://www.aarongoldenthal.com/post/2009/11/11/Using-jQuery-Impromptu-With-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have decided to alert user via alert then please go ahead with light box effect..

http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/30-efficient-jquery-lightbox-plugins/

if you are still would like to go ahead with traditional alert then obviously its easy for you to fire it up on page load rather than attaching script to it..

')" ....>

Because if you require any change then you just need to alter the javascript alone and you dont need to build project again to test it...

Hope its useful for you..

Note: I'm using my own DLLs to render content so above coding may requires alteration because i did forget traditional asp codings.. :)